# Correct JSON request body for nested ComplexType in XSD

Tags: java, json, xsd, jaxb

I have a Restful interface setup using XSD and the jaxb2-maven-plugin.  I am now trying to make a restful call and I cannot pass in a 'FilePair' properly.

XSD Snippet:

```
    <xsd:complexType name="FilePair">
           <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="requestFile" type="xsd:string" />
               <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="responseFile" type="xsd:string" />
           </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>

   <xsd:complexType name="ValidateCcmtaFileRequest">
       <xsd:sequence>
           <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestToken" type="xsd:string" />
           <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OnCompletionURI" type="xsd:string" />
           <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Fileset" type="tns:FilePair" />
       </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
```

The sample JSON body I am trying to send:

```
{
   "requestToken"  : "1234567",
   "onCompletionURI" : "http://someURL",
   "Fileset" : [
        {"requestFile" : "test.in", "responseFile" : "test.out"}
    ]
}
```

My questions is:
1) is my request body correct for the corresponding xsd and what is the correct JSON.
2) is there a tool where i can provide a full XSD and it generates JSON request bodies for me.

Comment: The part that you are showing looks correct to me. However if you share more details it might be easier to help solve your problem. Can you share some more of the XSD? The ValidateCcmtaFileRequest is somewhere used as the type for an Element, is it used in a larger xml construct? Also, are you getting any kind of error, if so please share that as well.  Also, welcome to SO

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review and provide some feedback. I was able to figure it out after walking away for a day and coming back to it.  I have provided the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The error with the original JSON was I used Fileset (capital F) instead of fileset (small F)
The correct JSON body is:

```
{
   "requestToken"  : "1234567",
   "onCompletionURI" : "http://someURL",
   "fileset" : [
        {"requestFile" : "test.in", "responseFile" : "test.out"}
    ]
}
```